# What is the word canonically used to mention reference coalescence

Tags: c++, reference

In C++ there is a mechanism that "coalesces" references in some template contexts, and for function pointers. `void (*)()` is equivalent to `void()`.

I've been trying to google it, but without the actual term it's impossible.

Comment: Even though I'd like to say congratulations, I don't see how the question can benefit any future reader. I'm therefore voting to close, but feel free to debate

Comment: @PasserBy Well I'd argue that google indexer can now link the word "coalesce" to "collapse", which will help people with the same train of thoughts I had. I could only think of "coalesce", I even used thesaurus to check synonyms, but nothing jumped to my eyes as the obvious term. In the end I had a vague memory that Meyers's article mentioned it so I re-read it until the word appeared. Which is O(N) search. A google query is O(1).

Comment: Why do you mention function pointer? It has nothing to do with reference collapsing.

Comment: @xskxzr I thought it had, how can I know before being able to research it ? it looks like a similar effect enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found it !! it's called `reference collapsing`

c.f. https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

```
void f(int& && param);           // initial instantiation of f with lvalue
```

> Because of the reference-to-reference, this instantiated code is prima
>   facie invalid, but the source code– “f(x)” – is completely reasonable.
>   To avoid rejecting it, **C++11 performs “reference collapsing” when
>   references to references arise in contexts such as template
>   instantiation**.